# There is a way to execute just a Maven subproject?

Tags: java, maven, module, subproject

I am wondering if there is a way to run a Maven subproject alone. I mean, in several code samples you can find a group of maven projects with a common parent. There is a way to replace parent in order to be able to run just a subproject.
Lets suppose this repository https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-examples
There is way to run just spring-boot-tutorial-soap-web-services/ project?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to the application class and run it from there
https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-examples/blob/master/spring-boot-tutorial-soap-web-services/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/springboot/soap/web/services/example/SpringBootTutorialSoapWebServicesApplication.java

Comment: Example repository in your question does not really make sense. To execute `spring-boot-tutorial-soap-web-services` just run `mvn` command inside the subfolder. This is really a standalone project with no relation to other parts of the repository.

Comment: Many thanks JockX, your advice is Ok to run the project. But I am looking even a way to extract completely the project. I mean to be able to open the project in an IDE without need POM´s parent. Perhaps merging both POMs in child or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

maven projects are identified by pom.xml and you can run any maven project individually. (Any maven goal).

1. cd into_a_maven_project(identified by pom.xml).
2. mvn install(this will run install phase for the project).

There are several relationships among maven projects.

1. Parent-child
2. Submodule
3. Dependency

Parent-child: This relationship is used in defining a pom. For instance, When a set of pom shares a lot, you can define a parent pom(parent maven project) and reference from the child project. (reference is done from child to parent)

When you run child project, the parent project is used only to inherit the pom(copy the content of parent pom). Child pom overrides the configuration in parent pom.(child pom contains little because of the fact that required configurations copied from the parent pom)

Submodule: This relationship is used when it makes sense to build multiple projects together. In this case, you run build in the project referencing submodules. (This is not a parent child relationships, the pom is not inherited if the project is not also a parent). The result is that the submodule projects become part of the build. (The order of the build is determined by dependencies between them)

Dependency: This relationship is used when the code in a project depended by your project. The build order is calculated using this relationship.